# What is the best way to store a user's Facebook friends list in my database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, facebook, facebook-graph-api

**Overview**

I'm creating a Ruby on Rails website which uses Facebook to login.

For each user I have a database entry which stores their Facebook User ID along with other basic information.

I'm also using the Koala gem in order to retrieve a user's friendlist from Facebook, but I'm unsure as to how I should store this data...

**Option 1**

I could store the user's friends as a serialized hash in the `User` table, then if I wanted to display a list of all the current user's friends, I could grab this hash and do something along the lines of `SELECT FROM Users WHERE facebook_user_id IN hash`

Each time the user logs in I could update this field to store the latest friends list.

**Option 2**

I could create a Friend table and store friendship information in here, where a User has many Friends. So there would be a row for each friendship, (`User1` and `User2` columns). Then to display a list of the current user's friends I could do something like `SELECT User2 FROM Friends WHERE User1 = current_user`

This seems like the better option to me, but...

It has the disadvantage that there would be many rows... If there were 100,000 users, each with 100 friends, that's now 10,000,000 rows in the Friends table.

It also means each time the user logs in, I'd need to loop over their Facebook friends list returned using Koala and create a Friend record if someone on their friendlist is in my User table and there isn't a corresponding entry in the Friends table. This seems like it'd be slow if a user has 1000 Facebook friends?

I'd appreciate any guidance on how it would be best to achieve this.

Apologies for the badly worded question, I'll try and reword/organise it shortly.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to store a lot of data, then you need to store a lot of data. If you are like most, you probably won't run into that problem sooner than you have the cash to solve it. In other words, you are probably assuming you'll have more traffic and data than you'll get, at least in the short-term. So I doubt this is an issue, even though it is a good sign that you are thinking about it now rather than later.

As I mentioned in my comment below, the easiest solution is to have a tie table with a row for each side of the friend relationship (a `has_many :friends, through: :facebook_friend_relationships, class_name: 'FacebookFriend'` on FacebookFriend, per the design mentioned below). But your question seemed to be about how to reduce the number of records, so that is what the remainder of the answer will address.

If you have to store in the DB and you know for sure that you will absolutely have every FB user on the planet hitting your site because it is so awesome, but they won't all hit at once, then if you are limited in storage, you may want to use a LRU algorithm (remove the least recently used records) possibly with timed expiration also. You could just have a cron job that does a query on the DB then deletes old/unused records to do this. Wouldn't be perfect, but it would be a simple solution.

You could also archive older data rather than throw it away. So, frequently used data could stay in the table of active users, and then you might offload older data to another table or even another database (and you might see the apartment and second_base gems for that). However, once you get to the size, you're probably looking at a number of other architectural solutions that have much less to do with ActiveRecord models/associations or schema design. Though it pays to plan ahead, I wouldn't worry about that excessively until you are sure that the application will get enough users to invest the time in that.

Even though ActiveRecord has some caching, you could just avoid the DB and cache friends in memory yourself in the beginning for speed, especially if you don't yet have many users, which you probably don't yet. If you think you'll run out of memory because of the high number of users, LRU might be a good option here also, and [lru_redux](https://github.com/SamSaffron/lru_redux) looks interesting. Again, you might want to time the cache also so expires and re-gets friends when the cache expires. Even just storing the results in the user session may be adequate, i.e. in the controller action method, just do `@friends ||= Something.find_friends(fb_user_id)`, and the latter is what most might do as a first shot at it while you're getting started.

If you use ActiveRecord, in your query in the controller (or on the association in the model) consider using `include:` to avoid n+1 queries. That will speed up things.

For the schema design, maybe:

- User - users table with email and authN info. Look at the Devise gem.
- FacebookUser - info about the Facebook user.
- FacebookFriendRelationship - a tie model with (id and) two columns, one for one FacebookUser id and one for the other.

By separating the authN info (User) from the FB data (FacebookUser and FacebookFriendRelationship), you make it easier to have other social media accounts, etc. each with information specific to those accounts in other tables.

The complexity comes in FacebookUser's relationship with friends if the goal is to minimize rows in the relationship table. To half the number of rows, you'd have a single row for a relationship where the id of FacebookUser could be in either foreign key column. Either the user has a friend or is a friend, so you could have two `has_many :through` associations on FacebookFriend that each use a different foreign key in FacebookFriendRelationship. Or you could do HABTM without the model and use foreign_key and association_foreign_key options in each association. Either way, you could add a method to add both associations together (because they are arrays). Instead, you could use custom SQL in a single has_many if you didn't care about having to use ActiveRecord to remove associations the normal way. However, per your comments, I think you want to avoid this complexity, and I agree with you, unless you really must limit the number of relationship rows. However, it isn't the number of tie table rows that will eat the data, it is going to be all of the user info you keep in the FacebookFriends table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right that never have that many users, I just wanted to learn the best way to do things. If I go with the schema you suggested, each time the user logs in I'd need to update the relationships table to create friendships for any of the user's friends which have signed up to my site since their last visit. This would require looping through their friends list and attempting to find a user in my database, and if one exists, create a new relationship entry if there isn't one already. Is this the most efficient way of doing things? It seems pretty inefficient.

Comment: Your goal seemed to be to have fewer records (per your 10,000,000 rows example in the question), so having as single row for each relationship vs. one record for each direction of the same relationship would half the number of rows (so would be 5,000,000). But, if you don't mind having possibly duplicate rows for each relationship, that would seem to be a better solution for your current needs.

Comment: Also, you are not (or at least shouldn't be) doing the looping in the controller to get each friend. Your query is and the database is (hopefully) good at that. To avoid n+1 queries like what you are alluding to, use the `:include` option to ensure when AR queries, it only queries once for each model type for a single lookup. You can optimize this even more, but in the beginning, you probably won't need to.

Comment: Once the database has entries to associate two users as friends I realise I could use User.friends.all or something along those lines. Initially though, when I get the friendlist back from Facebook as a hash of names and user_id's, I'll need to loop through this hash and attempt to find a user linked to that Facebook user_id in my User table for each one, won't I? Unless I do a select from users where facebook user_id is IN the list in that hash (but seeing as the list might be 1000 long, this doesn't seem like a good method?).

Comment: Ah, re: the `:include` comment, I assume you mean something like User.friends.all(:include => :users) to ensure it returns the Users associated with that friend entry?

Comment: Yes, I'm just talking about reducing the number of queries to look up the data. For destroy, could use [destroy_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/destroy_all) with conditions or call on AR relation. And, [update](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update) can take multiple records. Of course, you could just store a simplified JSON version of the friends for each user as well, but then you no longer have the relational normalized DB benefits, and when you need to query or update older data that might not have all the same fields/structure, it can be more difficult.